# I am getting a Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Years:"

Tags: java, jframe, runtime-error

This is one code file (i think this is where the error is but i might be mistaken) the run time error mentions "years: " which is located in this file. here is the full error. Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Years:"

> 

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
   A frame that shows the growth of an investment with variable interest,
   using a bar chart.
*/
public class InvestmentFrame4 extends JFrame
{
   private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 400;
   private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 400;

   private static final int CHART_WIDTH = 300;
   private static final int CHART_HEIGHT = 300;

   private static final double DEFAULT_RATE = 5;
   private static final double INITIAL_BALANCE = 1000;   

   private JLabel rateLabelInitialInvestment;
   private JLabel rateLabelInterestRate;
   private JLabel rateLabelYears;
   private JTextField rateFieldInitialInvestment;
   private JTextField rateFieldInterestRate;
   private JTextField rateFieldYears;
   private JButton button;
   private ChartComponent chart;
   private double balance;

   public InvestmentFrame4()
   {  
  //    balance = Double.parseDouble(rateLabelInitialInvestment.getText());
      chart = new ChartComponent(3 * INITIAL_BALANCE);
      chart.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CHART_WIDTH, CHART_HEIGHT));
      chart.append(INITIAL_BALANCE);

      createInterestRateTextField();
      createInitialInvestmentTextField();
      createYearsTextField();
      createButton();
      createPanel();

      setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
   }

   private void createInterestRateTextField()
   {
      rateLabelInterestRate = new JLabel("Interest Rate: ");

      final int FIELD_WIDTH = 25;
      rateFieldInterestRate = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
      rateFieldInterestRate.setText("" + DEFAULT_RATE);
   }

   private void createInitialInvestmentTextField()
   {
      rateLabelInitialInvestment = new JLabel("Initial Investment: ");

      final int FIELD_WIDTH = 20;
      rateFieldInitialInvestment = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
      rateFieldInitialInvestment.setText("" + DEFAULT_RATE);
   }

   private void createYearsTextField()
   {
      rateLabelYears = new JLabel("Years: ");

      final int FIELD_WIDTH = 20;
      rateFieldYears = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
      rateFieldYears.setText("" + DEFAULT_RATE);
   }

   class AddInterestListener implements ActionListener
   {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
      {
        for(int i = 1; i < Integer.parseInt(rateLabelYears.getText().trim()); i++)
        {
          balance = Double.parseDouble(rateLabelInitialInvestment.getText()) * Math.pow(1.0 + Double.parseDouble(rateLabelInterestRate.getText()), Integer.parseInt(rateFieldYears.getText()));
        }
      }            
   }

   private void createButton()
   {
      button = new JButton("Compound Interest");      

      ActionListener listener = new AddInterestListener();
      button.addActionListener(listener);
   }

   private void createPanel()
   {
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(rateLabelInitialInvestment);
      panel.add(rateFieldInitialInvestment);
      panel.add(rateLabelInterestRate);
      panel.add(rateFieldInterestRate);
      panel.add(rateLabelYears);
      panel.add(rateFieldYears);
      panel.add(button);
      panel.add(chart);      
      add(panel);
   }
}
```

Here is another file

```
public class ChartComponent extends JComponent
{
   private ArrayList<Double> values;
   private double maxValue;

   public ChartComponent(double max)
   {
      values = new ArrayList<Double>();
      maxValue = max;
   }

   public void append(double value)
   {
      values.add(value);
      repaint();
   }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {  
      final int GAP = 5;
      final int BAR_HEIGHT = 10;

      int y = GAP;
      for (double value : values)
      {
         int barWidth = (int) (getWidth() * value / maxValue);
         g.fillRect(0, y, barWidth, BAR_HEIGHT);
         y = y + BAR_HEIGHT + GAP;
      }
    }
}
```

and finally the main

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
   This program displays the growth of an investment, showing
   a bar chart.
*/
public class InvestmentViewer4
{  
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {  
      JFrame frame = new InvestmentFrame4();
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

if someone could please explain i am getting the run time error it would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: `Years:` can not be converted to a number ... I would have through the exception was self explanatory, I'm not sure what the problem actually is - did you try doing a search for `java.lang.NumberFormatException`?

Comment: the error is within your for loop, one Label has the title "years" and you're trying to parse that to an int, did you mean to get the text of a text field?

Answer (score 0):

the problem occurs here:

```
for(int i = 1; i < Integer.parseInt(rateLabelYears.getText().trim()); i++)
```

`rateLabelYears` is a `JLabel`, that will always have the text of `"years"` unless you change it otherwise. You've mistaken it with the `rateFieldYears` which is an identifier to the `JTextField` that takes input for the years.

you'll need this:

```
for(int i = 1; i < Integer.parseInt(rateFieldYears.getText().trim()); i++){
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```